# Bold a certain value of a specified column in a specific grid - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I have miniature problem. First, I'm using **vb.net**. 
What I want is to get the same value from a column that I could only those values thicken and in some way to express more than in other in my **gridview (devexpres grid)**.

[image]

In my picture you can see the name of the first column and the cell values. I want only the name 'KLASA'  TO CHANGE IN THE SAME NAME ONLY BOLD (for each cell named 'KLASA').

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [RowCellStyle](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowCellStyletopic) event:

Using the example found on that page, you can get the class that makes up the row like this:

```
Dim View As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView = sender
Dim ClassX As MyClass = View.GetRow(e.RowHandle) 'This would be the type of data you set as the datasource for the grid
```

Then read you value or do whatever you need to here to figure out if it should be bold and set the appearance like this:

```
e.Appearance.Font = New Font(f.FontFamily, f.Size, FontStyle.Bold)
```